# How to go to the last record

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I have this code to add data to a grid.
After adding data, I want to go to the last row.

When I write `dataGrid.dataProvider.length-1` it goes before last row.
But when I write `dataGrid.dataProvider.length` nothing happens. 
What's wrong?

```
var que3:Que = new Que();
createQueResult.token = queService.createQue(que3);
createQueResult.token =queService.commit();
createQueResult.token =queService.getAllQue();
dataGrid.ensureCellIsVisible(dataGrid.dataProvider.length-1,1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that dataGrid.dataProvider.length is greater than the highested index. If the method ensureCellIsVisible is not showing the last row then it may be a bug in that method. You can try calling datagrid.validateNow() before or after that call and see if it helps.